# #Error in confusionMatrix.default: the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Tags: r

I've been working on my capstone project and cannot seem to get past this last error with the confusionMatrix. The only solution on here that sort of worked I have listed below but after trying 7 different ideas from stackoverflow nothing has worked. Any ideas or assistance would be great!

Total data set has 744 observations and I've split into a test/train grouping.
I am running a regression random forest to predict the LAT. Test Data has 186 observations which is why rf.preds has 186 levels but my test$LAT reference has 136 levels.

I believe this is happening as I have duplicate numbers in the LAT column of my test set.

Sample data:

```
Date       LAT (in hours)
5/1/2016   3.55
5/1/2016   4.25
5/1/2016   6.91
5/1/2016   1.49
5/1/2016   2.11
5/1/2016   3.33
5/1/2016   1.76
5/1/2016   0.66
```

```r
rf_tuned <- randomForest( LAT~., data = train, ntree=500, mtry=2, importance=TRUE)

rf.preds <- predict(rf_tuned, newdata=test,)

results <- data.frame(actual = round(test$LAT, 2), predicted = round(rf.preds, 2))
test.lat <- as.factor(test$LAT)

rf.preds <- as.factor(rf.preds)

confusionMatrix(rf.preds,test.lat) 

#Error in confusionMatrix.default(rf.preds, test.lat) : 
  the data cannot have more levels than the reference
```

TRIED:

```r
predictions <- predict(rf_tuned, newdata=test)

ext_u <- union(predictions, test$LAT)

ext_table <- table(factor(predictions, ext_u),factor(test$LAT,ext_u))

dim(ext_table)

confusionMatrix(ext_table)
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! It would be much easier for the community to help you if you would provide some sample data in your question that reproduces the error you are seeing. Here's some [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to write a minimal reproducible example. It's also helpful to provide details about your error messages (quote the actual error message).

Comment: `confusionMatrix` is applicable for classification problem. But from your description, it appears that your problem is regression rather than classification. It will be more clear if you can provide `dput(head(train)` or `structure(train)`. Under such situation, you should use R2, RMSE etc. rather than `confusionMatrix`.

Comment: thank you xilliam. My error is the title of the question but I will add it to the body and include sample data.